# SQL-Server Select returning null on PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a query that returns all the data while running at MSSQL, but when I try to get the result with php code it returns null

SELECT:

```
   $query =  "SELECT  DISTINCT (E080SER.desser) as desser,
                E080SER.CODFAM codfam, e085cli.apecli apecli, 
                E085CLI.CODCLI codcli, E085CLI.NOMCLI nomeCli
                FROM
                E160CTR,
                E160CVS, e080ser,
                E085CLI,
                E070EMP,
                E070FIL
                WHERE
                e070emp.nomemp like '%Gestão tech%' and 
                e080ser.codser = e160cvs.codser and
                e080ser.codser like ('%manw%') and (E160CTR.CODEMP = 1)  and
                ((E160CTR.CODEMP = E070FIL.CODEMP) AND (E160CTR.CODFIL = 
                E070FIL.CODFIL) AND  
                (E160CTR.CODCLI = E085CLI.CODCLI) AND (E160CVS.CODEMP = 
                E160CTR.CODEMP) AND 
                (E160CVS.CODFIL = E160CTR.CODFIL) AND (E160CVS.NUMCTR = 
                E160CTR.NUMCTR)) AND
                (E160CTR.SITCTR = 'A') and e080ser.sitser = 'a' and 
                E080SER.CODEMP IN (1, 9)
                  order by e080ser.desser";
```

PHP CODE:

```
 $sql = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
 while($item = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql)){
    var_dump($item);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _... the result within php code it returns null_ - that `$item` is `null` for all rows? And you need to check `$sql` after `$sql = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);`.

Comment: Yes, it is null for all rows. I don't know, i think that it is something with the SELECT, because when I try this routine with some other query, it runs properly

Comment: OK, then can you place `print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));` after `$sql = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);` call to check for errors? And `if ($sql === false) {...}`is actual error checking.

Comment: I've tried that, and returns nothing

Comment: Strange, your code seems correct (except error checking). Are you sure you execute this statement against the correct database (I assume that `sqlsrv_query()` returns many empty rows)?

Comment: Yes Zhorov, it is correct, running some other select on the same database returns the result, but this one returns nothing. I really don't know what's the problem. I've checked with some guys here on my job and no one is able to find what is going on. Obs: running it directly on the database returns a lot of rows (97 to be exact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem

The problem was the encoding, I put the $query inside of utf8_encode(), and now it is returning the results.

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's necessary to fetch all result sets with [sqlsrv_next_result()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-next-result?view=sql-server-2017) to get your data. You may try with this:

```
<?php
...
$sql = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
do {
   while($item = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql)){
      var_dump($item);
   }
} while (sqlsrv_next_result($sql));
...

?>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what "sometimes" means. I see data when using your code - while var_dump($sql) returns null.

Comment: @Gerfried, when `sqlsrv_query()` executes a complex statement, for example `INSERT ...; SELECT ...; `, the count of the affected rows will be returned as a separate result set. So, in this case, `sqlsrv_next_result()` makes the next result active. Another option is using `SET NOCOUNT ON;`

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra semicolon after the while loop, i.e. the body of the loop is empty. Then the result you try to read is after the last row, that's why you don't get what you expected.

Comment: Thank you, Andrey, but, actually, that was a little mistake because of the tests that I was running. Even without the semicolon, it returns null